# Help to identify CAN packets of a lift-fork

Tags: can, bus, protocol

I have monitored the CAN bus of a lift-fork but I can't recognize the meaning of the packets that was being sent periodically on the bus. Do somebody have an idea on how to interpret these packets below? Or know what is the protocol? Its all in decimal format.

```
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"1956","dlc":1,"data":[23]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"660","dlc":4,"data":[0,0,0,0]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"916","dlc":8,"data":[65,80,0,0,0,16,0,1]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"648","dlc":4,"data":[0,0,0,0]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"904","dlc":8,"data":[65,78,0,0,0,48,8,0]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"916","dlc":8,"data":[65,80,0,0,0,16,0,65]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"1544","dlc":8,"data":[64,10,16,1,0,0,0,0]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"520","dlc":3,"data":[32,0,6]}
{"format":"std","rtr":0,"id":"521","dlc":8,"data":[0,0,3,0,1,0,0,13]}
```

**EDIT, packets in HEX:**

```
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x0D 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x13 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x12 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x14 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x15 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x1B 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x20 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x19 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x21 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x26 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x1C 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x27 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x28 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x2D 
New standard frame from 0x0000060D, DLC 3, Data 0x35 0x77 0x13 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x20 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x2E 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x33 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x23 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x34 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x3A 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x27 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x3B 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x07 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x08 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x31 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x0F 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x35 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x15 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x38 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x1B 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x1C 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x21 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x3C 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x22 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x3F 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x28 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x29 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x2E 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x2F 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x03 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x06 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x35 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x36 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x3B 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00 
New standard frame from 0x00000388, DLC 8, Data 0x01 0x4E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x50 0x00 0x40 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x0A 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x3C 
New standard frame from 0x00000209, DLC 8, Data 0x1E 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x01 
New standard frame from 0x00000394, DLC 8, Data 0x41 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x41 
New standard frame from 0x00000208, DLC 3, Data 0x20 0x00 0x0D 
New standard frame from 0x000003C0, DLC 5, Data 0x00 0xFD 0x00 0xF5 0x00
```

Comment: which lift-fork? There's more than one brand in the market. Over here we call them 'forklifts'

Comment: See if you can find any protocol specification on the part number of the joysticks.

Comment: the data could be binary ... possibly just one or two bits for some function ... it may help to display the data as binary or hexadecimal

Comment: @abomin3v3l i don't mean to be rude, but your reputation level indicates that you should know better than to ask a question with missing information ... furthermore, this is a Q&A site, so ask a question about the problem, not about people's knowledge ... ask `how to interpret these packets below?` ... do not ask `does anybody know .....?`  .... the first question gives you information ... the second question gives you `yes`

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't interpret CAN bus data unless you know which application layer protocol it uses. Custom ones are common. CANopen and J1939 are the popular standardized ones.

> Its all in decimal format

That's useless, get a better tool that displays hex. If I saw the hex identifiers I might be able to identify it, but I can't be bothered to convert them for you.

Comment: I did edited the topic and added the packets in hex format